# Unknown module(s) in QT: chart

Tags: qt, qtcharts

I have the same problem in [Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710908/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-charts#) ; but my problem on Mac OS. I can not reply on that topic, so i open the new one.

I build on Qt Creator 4.6.0 and based on Qt 5.10.1 (Clang 7.0 (Apple), 64 bit). Can you help me get the solution for how to use the Qtchart in my project?

```
QT += quick
QT += chart
```

[Explain the old problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5epm.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a missing Qt module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200094/how-to-install-a-missing-qt-module)

Comment: @Mike I also turn on qtchart. But, this is not the problem. I have added new image extend that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it is simply "charts" with an "s"?

```
QT += charts
```

Comment: I changed to charts. But this problem also continues.
"found not working imports:...... Qtchart is not installed."

Comment: Could you include the log containing the error? Are you sure you use the right Kit for Qt5.10? Can you try with a working example like [this one](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtcharts-linechart-example.html) ?

Comment: It can run with the example. But cannot run in the project. The log is: `found not working imports file:...../main.qml:5 module "Qtchart" is not installed`. Coding on Line 5 is `import QtCharts 2.2`

Comment: Ok, then you can have a look at that QML example [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtcharts-qmlaxes-example.html), and try to decrement QtCharts version to 2.1/2.0 just for test purposes.